# Converting images to pdfs server side

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, type-conversion

I'm currently working on a project involving converting form results to a downloadable PDF, which is simple enough. I was recently asked, however, to add attachment functionality. I'm using dompdf to convert the form results to PDF, but is there a way to convert the attachments separately (can be jpg, png, doc/x, or pdf) to a PDF file and then append the attachment file to the dompdf output?

I can handle the implementation; are there any free libraries that will support anything like this? I found [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/), which supports images, but it does not support Word files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you will need to find a library for every kind of conversion you need (you mentioned jpg, png, and doc/x, but you didn't say if that was all of them.)

For common office formats, you can launch a headless (meaning it can run on a server without a graphical display) instance of OpenOffice or LibreOffice. Then you can interact with it from various programming languages, or you can use a ready-made commandline tool such as [pyodconverter](https://github.com/mirkonasato/pyodconverter), to ask it to convert between various file formats. This is the best way to convert doc and docx files to pdf, by the way, short of spending money on Microsoft software.

As for "appending the attachment file", by which I take it you mean concatenating a bunch of PDF files together, you can use the free tool [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/).